# Pre-compiling ASP.NET solution causes error in integrated mode on IIS7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, msbuild

We have a site that we are trying to move to IIS7 on Windows Server 2008 R2 that was previously hosted on IIS6 on Windows Server 2003.

The problem (to me at least) is really strange.

If I precompile the site using our website deployment build scripts (which produces COMPILED files in the BIN directory) and place it on the server with “Managed Pipeline Mode” set to “Integrated” we get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821' or one of its
>   dependencies. Access is denied.

If I change “Managed Pipeline Mode” to “Classic” – it works.  I'd prefer not to leave it running in Classic mode.

If I leave “Managed Pipeline Mode” set to “Integrated” and just copy the Web solution directly onto the server without running it through our build scripts to get it into a precompiled state – it works in Integrated mode.

***What could precompiling the solution possible doing to it that would cause the Access is denied error for log4net only in Integrated mode?***

Comment: When you've precompiled the binaries and dropped them on the server, have you confirmed that the log4net dll is in the bin folder for the web app?  If you turn on Fusion Logging, you should be able to see the actual assembly binding error when it's looking for that file.  Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Nick - Thanks for the tip.  I used the Fusion Logger which ends with these three lines:


LOG: Assembly Name is: log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821
ERR: Setup failed with hr = 0x80070005.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80070005). Probing terminated.

Comment: And just to be clear - I'm not sure where to go from that error in Fusion logger.  Suggestions?

Comment: my googling is indicating that it's a StrongName issue.  Is log4net strong named?  are you strong naming your dlls when you precompile?

Comment: Nick - by doing some googling I found it was a permission issue.  I changed the permission on IIS in the Anonymous Authentication to use "Application pool identity" which I made sure had rights to the temporary asp.net folder and it's working now.  Thanks for getting me in the right direction!!!!

Comment: Well thank you for circling back and letting me know.  sorry I wasn't more help